# c# lotus dbase ODBC charset

Tags: c#, character-encoding, dbase

i am trying to read an lotus dbase file in order to export the data.
i am using this code:

```
enter code here
    private void odbc()
    {
        DataTable YourResultSet = new DataTable();
        string strAccessConn = @"Driver={Microsoft dBase Driver (*.dbf)};SourceType=DBF;SourceDB=C:\shares\lotus;Exclusive=No;NULL=NO;DELETED=NO;BACKGROUNDFETCH=NO;CHARSET=928";

        OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(strAccessConn);

        // Open the connection, and if open successfully, you can try to query it
        connection.Open();

        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            string mySQL = @"select * from C:\shares\lotus\techtime.DBF";  // dbf table name

            OdbcCommand MyQuery = new OdbcCommand(mySQL, connection);
            OdbcDataAdapter DA = new OdbcDataAdapter(MyQuery);

            DA.Fill(YourResultSet);

            connection.Close();
        }

        string myString = YourResultSet.Rows[0][4].ToString();
    }
```

but the greek leters appears like this "╠┴═╧╙ ═╔╩╧╦╧╒─╟╙"
i do not know the charset been used.
what can i do?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should use 737 code page in your connection string:

```
;CHARSET=737
```